# Report Viewer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

Hi i am using report viewer in my asp.net application. this is my first experience with report viewer.so kindly help me.
the issue i am facing is,all the resources on net are fetching from db and they simply provide that data table to report viewer.
i can not do this. i have complex tables,calculations etc. 
for that i have my own custom class which provides different methods.each method return some specific information.
so now my point is, i want to use my own custom class that has data i want to use that class. but dont know how to do that.
kindly provide me some resource link,tutorial,any thing that can help.
Kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: check it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in two ways

1. use object data source
2. XML source

As you are inclined towards object source. Populate your custom object class after gathering data from multiple sources.
Following articles will help you achieve this
[Report with Object Source in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReportViewerObject04172007111636AM/ReportViewerObject.aspx)

OR

[All options mentioned briefly here , but code is in VB.NET](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/asp-net/binding-data-to-the-reportviewer-control-dynamically-in-asp-net-2-0/)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but my class contains lists of other classes.its a complete entity model.so still object source can be used?

Comment: Yes you can use. And especially I think those will be used incase you have to generate any subreports

Comment: The following link will give you an idea how this is possible http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-working-reportviewer-with-a-complex-business-object-with-a-nested-generic-list-type-property-as-data-source-for-local-reports.aspx

Comment: if this worked for you please mark the question as answered. good luck..